# c# call items in nested list

Tags: c#, list, nested, call

I'm learning to program in C#, and I'm running into a problem: I can't seem to call the elements that I've previously stored in a nested List, like so:

```
private List<List<float>> Order = new List<List<float>>();
private List<float> SubList = new List<float>();
private List<float> Conditions = new List<float>();

string tmp;
string[] levels;
string[] sublevels;
float curlevel;

tmp = "1,2,3;1,3,2;2,1,3;2,3,1;3,1,2;3,2,1"
levels = tmp.Split(';');
for(int i=0;i<levels.Length;i++){
    sublevels=levels[i].Split(',');
    for(int a=0;a<sublevels.Length;a++){
        float.TryParse(sublevels[a], out curlevel);
        SubList.Add(curlevel);
    }
    Order.Add(SubList);
    SubList.Clear();
}

foreach(float cond in Order[3]){
    Conditions.Add(cond);
}
```

Although printing the lists' counts shows that my Order list now has 6 items, and each SubList list has 3 items in it, I am not able to call the items in the sublists by indexing the Order list, and therefore my Conditions list, which I want to use in my project, stays empty. Is there another way to index items within a nested list? I also tried:

```
Conditions[0]=Order[3][0];
Conditions[1]=Order[3][1];
Conditions[2]=Order[3][2];
```

Which also didn't work. If anyone knows how to do this, I would be very grateful to have your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you code to

```
 List<List<float>> Order = new List<List<float>>();
        //List<float> SubList = new List<float>();
        List<float> Conditions = new List<float>();

        string tmp;
        string[] levels;
        string[] sublevels;
        float curlevel;

        tmp = "1,2,3;1,3,2;2,1,3;2,3,1;3,1,2;3,2,1";
        levels = tmp.Split(';');
        for (int i = 0; i < levels.Length; i++)
        {
            List<float> SubList = new List<float>();
            sublevels = levels[i].Split(',');
            for (int a = 0; a < sublevels.Length; a++)
            {
                float.TryParse(sublevels[a], out curlevel);
                SubList.Add(curlevel);
            }
            Order.Add(SubList);
            //SubList.Clear();
        }

        foreach (float cond in Order[3])
        {
            Conditions.Add(cond);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work of the keys really are numeric. I think you clear your sublist and lose your data with  `SubList.Clear();` Your first step is to put a breakpoint before and after you do this and Inspect your elements and what they look like.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the following linq query to achieve what you want:

```
var result = tmp.Split(';')
                .Select(b => b.Split(',')
                .Select(float.Parse)
                .ToArray())
             .ToList();

foreach (float cond in result[3])
{
    Console.WriteLine(cond);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the others write, it is your SubList.Clear() which removes all elements from SubList inside your Order List.

You can use

```
Order.Add(new List<float>(SubList));
```

This makes sures there is no reference from SubList.clear() and the list you just added to Order